# Passing <Grid /> props with ...rest/spread and adding component="a" fails with type errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to pass some props to  Material-ui component like this:

```
<Foo href="/" label="Very main page" zeroMinWidth />
```

and the `<Foo />` is something like this:

```
import { GridProps } from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

interface IProps extends GridProps {
  href?: string;
  label?: string;
}

export const Foo = ({
  href, label, ...gridProps
}: IProps) => {
  return (
    <Grid item component="a" href={href} {...gridProps}>
      {label}
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

And I receive an error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: "a"; } & Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment; ... 7 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ xs?: boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11; sm?: boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11; md?: boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11; ... 271 more ...; target: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>, "dir" | ... 262 more ... | "referrerPolicy"> & { ...; }, "dir" | ... 261 more ... | "referrerPolicy">'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type '((instance: HTMLDivElement) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLAnchorElement) => void) | RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLDivElement) => void' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLAnchorElement) => void) | RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
            Type '(instance: HTMLDivElement) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLAnchorElement) => void'.
              Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
                Property 'align' is missing in type 'HTMLAnchorElement' but required in type 'HTMLDivElement'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ xs?: boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11; sm?: boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11; md?: boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11; ... 271 more ...; target: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment; ... 7 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | 2 | 1 | "auto" | 12 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11>> & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment; ... 7 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
```

Why this happens and how to fix this?

And if I remove `{...spread}` or if I remove `component="a"` it builds well.

I have found solution with spread of spread, like this:

```
  <Grid 
    {...{
      item: true,
      component: "a",
      href: href,
      ...gridProps
    }}
  >
    {label}
  </Grid>
```

But it looks some kind of weird and ugly...